# How to use fill_in with find in Capybara (if possible)

Tags: find, capybara

I'd like to do the following but can't due to the nature of fill_in expecting a locator as the first argument.

```
find(:css, "input[id$='donation_pledge_hundreds']").fill_in :with => "10"
```

I've also tried doing

```
element = find(:css, "input[id$='donation_pledge_hundreds']")   
fill_in element.<method> , :with => "10"
```

but there are no methods that return any data to identify the element to fill_in.

Any ideas of the best way of finding a field via a regex for use with fill_in?

Answer (score 170, accepted):

If you have a reference to the element itself you'd use `set` instead of `fill_in`:

```
find(:css, "input[id$='donation_pledge_hundreds']").set("10")
```

However for your specific example, `fill_in` should be able to find the element as you know it's ID:

```
fill_in 'donation_pledge_hundreds', with: "10"
```

Comment: Good man, That's the one. That particular field is used in different contexts (authenticated/not authenticated) and so takes a different field id. donation_pledge_hundreds is the common part of the field id hence comparing the end of the field name $=

Comment: Be careful using 'set' rather than the other built-in methods, as it doesn't trigger events after changing the value.

Comment: @DanCaddigan and that's why it seems f3ck3d up :/ how do you do then ?

Comment: You can use `find(:css, "...").set("10").send_keys(:return)` to press return afterwards. It triggers the relevant events. I've not tested it but you can also `find(:css, "...").set("10").trigger(:blur)` if that's your thing.

Answer (score 8):

```
element = find(:css, "input[id$='donation_pledge_hundreds']")   
element.fill_in with: "10"
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23104752)

Comment: This works well, thanks for letting us know you can omit the `within` part (i.e., the first argument).

Answer (score 6):

Instead of a method, you can use brackets to return `:name` or `:id`, e.g.

`element = find(:css, "input[id$='donation_pledge_hundreds']")
fill_in element[:name], :with => "10"`

The same approach can be used with `select` -

`select my_type, from: find('select[name$="[type]"]')[:name]`

Answer (score 4):

```
find("input[id$='donation_pledge_hundreds']").set "10"
```

It's worth noting that you can chain your finds.

```
@modal = find(".modal")
@modal.find('input[name=foo]').set "bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fill_in <$id>, :with => 'text you want to fill in'
```