# Clear masked input field in Capybara and Rspec

Tags: selenium, rspec, capybara

Is there a way for an input field to be cleared before entering some text into it. I'm fairly new to writing capybara with rspec and I have some trouble with masked input fields.

Here's the method I tried:


`find('AddressZip').clear 

fill_in('AddressZip', :with => '77487')`

I tried searching for similar methods, but haven't found anything.
Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there are any better solutions but I've been using this

```
 page.execute_script("$('#{field_id}').val('');")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, appreciate it. Turns out there is a much simpler method, clicking the input field first and then using the fill_in method will work.

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge, execute_script ignores scopes defined using **whithin**.
It's verbose too.

Better to use either

```
fill_in locator, with: ''
```

or

```
find(complex_selector).set ''
```

as described in the accepted answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534365/how-to-use-fill-in-with-find-in-capybara-if-possible)

Answer (score 2):

Normally clearing a text field is as simple as `fill_in locator, with: ''` but this did not work for me with a certain field controlled by a Vue.js component.
After trying 5 different workarounds proposed on SO I ended up having to resort to using the `send_keys` method with `:backspace`, E.G:

`10.times { find(:css, "input[name$='title']").send_keys(:backspace) }`