# Capybara can find but not fill_in

Tags: capybara

I am having some very strange behaviour with Capybara. It stubbornly refuses to fill in the fields of my login form.

```
<fieldset>
  <div class="clearfix">
    <label for="user_email">E-Mail Adresse</label>
    <div class="input">
      <input id="user_email" name="user[email]" size="30" type="email" value="">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="clearfix">
    <label for="user_password">Passwort</label>
    <div class="input">
      <input id="user_password" name="user[password]" size="30" type="password" value="">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="clearfix">
    <div class="input">
      <input name="user[remember_me]" type="hidden" value="0">
      <input id="user_remember_me" name="user[remember_me]" type="checkbox" value="1">
      <label for="user_remember_me">angemeldet bleiben</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

And here is where the fun begins:

```
within("#login_form"){ find("#user_email")}                                              
=> #<Capybara::Element tag="input" path="/html/body/div[2]/div[@id='content']/div/div[1]/form[@id='login_form']/fieldset/div[1]/div/input[@id='user_email']">
within("#login_form"){ fill_in("#user_email", with: "foo@example.com")}                  
Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find field "#user_email"
```

I don't quite understand how it is possible to be able to find, and yet not find, an element.
Another pair of eyes on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `fill_in('user_email', :with => 'foo@example.com')`, without the `#`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The locator for `find` and `fill_in` are different:

- [`find`](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders#find-instance_method) - When the first parameter is not a symbol, it is assumed to be the Capybara.default_selector - ie a css-selector or xpath.
- [`fill_in`](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions#fill_in-instance_method) - The first parameter is the field's name, id or label text.

The string "#user_email" represents a css-selector. This is why it works in `find` but not `fill_in`.

For `fill_in` to work, you need to just pass in the id value - ie just "user_email".

```
within("#login_form"){ fill_in("user_email", with: "foo@example.com")}
```

Comment: Hi @Justin Ko , I m working on a framework where in all locator values are stored in an excel and hence I'd be interested in using the element already found using 'find' to perform any action..as i'll have no freedom to again check on other attributes of that element just for 'fill_in'
Is there any alternate?

Comment: Just wanted to know if I can fill in data to a form field found using `find`. I guess answer is using of `#set`.

Answer (score 10):

you can do `find("#user_email").set "foo@example.com"`.  See answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8544650/3163914

Answer (score 1):

if it is an autocomplete field, you can use this:

```rb
  def fill_in_autocomplete(id, value)
    page.execute_script("document.getElementById('#{id}').setAttribute('value', '#{value}');")
  end
```