# How do the Capybara set and fill_in differ?

Tags: capybara

Recently I found that elements found using '`find`' of capybara may not work properly with `'fill_in`'( Refer:[Capybara can find but not fill_in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18879566/capybara-can-find-but-not-fill-in))

So the params used by fill_in and find are different. Hence I can use `set` and fill my form fields found using '`find`' is what I have observed.

Is there any other difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of actually inputting the field, `set` and `fill_in` are exactly the same.

The method definition for `fill_in` is:

```
def fill_in(locator, options={})
  raise "Must pass a hash containing 'with'" if not options.is_a?(Hash) or not options.has_key?(:with)
  with = options.delete(:with)
  fill_options = options.delete(:fill_options)
  find(:fillable_field, locator, options).set(with, fill_options)
end
```

As you can see on the last line, the `fill_in` method is doing the same thing - ie using `find` to get the node and then inputting it with `set`.