# Capybara's fill_in on a Site Prism's page object doesn't work

Tags: capybara, pageobjects, site-prism

I'm rewriting feature specs to page objects and I have a problem with `fill_in` method.

The code is as follows:

Page object:

```
class LoginPage < SitePrism::Page
 set_url '/login'

 section :navbar, NavbarSection, '.navbar-collapse'
 section :drop_menu, DropMenuSection, '.popover-content'
 element :email, 'input[name=email]'
 element :password, 'input[type=password]'
 element :submit, 'button[type=submit]'
 element :help, 'a', text: "Help! I can't sign in"
end
```

Spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

feature 'Login', js: true do
  let(:app) { App.new }
  let(:login_page) { app.login }

  scenario 'with invalid credentials results in error message' do
    login_page.load
    login_page.fill_in login_page.email, with: 'wrong@mail.com'
    login_page.fill_in login_page.password, with: 'bad password'
    login_page.submit.click
    expect(login_page).to have_content 'Invalid credentials'
  end
```

The input field is defined like this:

```
<input class="form-control input-lg ng-pristine ng-untouched 
ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" name="email" 
ng-model="login.credentials.email" placeholder="Email"
required="" tabindex="0" aria-required="true" 
aria-invalid="true">`
```

When I run the test, I get the following error:

```
[2] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Login>)> login_page.fill_in login_page.email, 
with: 'wrong@mail.com'
Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find field #<Capybara::Node::Element 
tag="input" path="/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/div/input">
```

However, this field is findable:

```
[1] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Login>)> login_page.email
=> #<Capybara::Node::Element tag="input" 
path="/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/div/input">
```

I guess it might be connected with how `fill_in` uses `find` when CSS are used.

Is there any way to handle it as close as possible to how the end user would interact with the form? 
I don't want to use `login_page.email.set 'wrong@mail.com'`, because `set` doesn't care if the field is actually clickable/fillable and not hidden by some element.

Answer (score 1):

Capbaras `#fill_in` is basically implemented as  `find(:fillable_field, "the id/name/label text").set("value to set")`.  Site-prism moves the find behavior to element, but does allow you to specify the selector used when specifying the element.  So rather than doing

```
element :email, "some css to find the email field"
```

you can do

```
element :email, :fillable_field, "the id/name/label you would have passed to fill_in"
```

which should make `login_page.email.set("xyz")` equivalent to using Capybaras fill_in.  The same can be done with :checkbox, :radio_button, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this works:

```
login_page.fill_in login_page.email[:name], with: 'wrong@mail.com'
```

The `[:name]` symbol is any unique input attribute you may have in the code.

This helped me [How to use fill_in with find in Capybara (if possible)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534365/how-to-use-fill-in-with-find-in-capybara-if-possible/32514424#32514424)

Comment: What do you mean by "The [:name] symbol is any unique input attribute you may have in the code". I mainly struggle with the term "input attribute". Do you mean you must specify an existing attribute from the input element, so you chose `:name` from `...name="password"...` ?

Comment: Turns out I pasted wrong html code - I edited the snippet to fit email field and not password :) And yes, you specify an existing attribute for the input element that is unique for that element (no other element on the page has it)